# Need help in understanding the method used in solution to find $676767....$(208 digits) mod 53

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Question :- $676767....$(208 digits) mod 53

---

Solution given :-
67 has been assumed to be k in some base higher than 67, so 67 would be a single digit in that base, let it be k

So question turns out to $kkkk...$(104 times) mod 53 which will equate to 0 since a number with (p-1) digits repeated, when divided by p gives a remainder of 0 , where p is a prime number

---

My doubt :-
I did not understand this base conversion thing, does this property ("a number with (p-1) digits repeated, when divided by p gives a remainder of 0, where p is a prime number ")  hold true in all bases ? How can we divide numbers with different bases ? Why are we not converting 53 as well to higher base ?

Comment: Are you familiar with Fermat's little theorem:  $a^{p-1}$ gives remainder $1$ when divided by $p$ if $a$ is not divisible by $p$?

Comment: Note: you have to be at least a little careful with the base.  $4444$ is not divisible by $5$, for example.

Comment: This (common) argument is explained in the linked dupe (and many other answers).

Comment: I simplified the argument in the linked dupe. Note that the linked dupe is one of *your* questions a few months prior. Hopfully by now the general method is clear (if not please ask questions in the linked dupe - not here - since this may get deleted since there in nothing new here).

Answer (score 2):

Base conversion not needed.

The originally presented number can be re-expressed as

$$67 \times \left[ ~1 + (10^2)  + (10^2)^2 + \cdots +   (10^2)^{103} ~\right]. \tag1 $$

Using the formula for the partial sum of a geometric series, you have that

$$1 + x + x^2 + \cdots + x^n = \frac{x^{n+1} - 1}{x-1}.$$

This means that the expression in (1) above can be re-expressed as

$$67 \times \frac{(10^2)^{104} - 1}{10^2 - 1} =  
67 \times \frac{(10^4)^{52} - 1}{10^2 - 1}. \tag2 $$

Here is where things get tricky.

$\pmod{53},~$ you have that $(10^2 - 1) \not\equiv  0.$

As has already been indicated by one of the comments, by [Fermat's Little Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem), you have that $~(10^4)^{52} - 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{53}.$

So, in (2) above, the denominator is not $~\equiv 0 \pmod{53}~$ and one of the factors in the numerator is $~\equiv 0 \pmod{53}.$

So, the overall expression must evaluate to $~0 \pmod{53}.$

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: @PeterPhipps +1 : nice catch, thanks.  answer edited.